# Создание документации к функции Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, документация

почти месяц как начал учить питон. Возник вопрос, как писать документацию к функции, чтобы не закидали палками?

```
def validator(user_input):
    """
    This function checks the user input for the presence of digits in the string,
    if there are no digits in the string - returns True. Else returns False

    :param user_input: string
    :return: bool
    """
    chars = list(user_input)
    for item in chars:
        if str(item).isdigit():
            return False
    else:
        return True
```

Вот пример того, как я пишу документацию. Как делать это правильно, что писать в return, parameters? Пишу в PyCharm, поэтому автоматически создаётся такой шаблон, а я понятия не имею как заполнить его.

Comment: Можете ещё аннотации указать `def validator(user_input: str) -> None:`.

Comment: Насколько я нашел, нет единого стандартного решения, что именно писать в докстринг. Есть несколько вариантов, см. вот этот ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24385103/4752653 . Шаблон, который подставляет PyCharm - это вариант [reStructuredText](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReStructuredText). В строках с параметрами и return желательно описывать за что отвечает каждый параметр и что конкретно означает возвращаемое значение. Аннотации типов также желательно делать, но это уже больше чем просто средство документирования.

Comment: `validator` - плохое имя для функции. Простое правило: функция - глагол (что она делает или на какой вопрос отвечает), переменная/класс- существительное (что это). Эту функцию можно назвать `is_valid()`, или `has_no_numbers()`, так она сообщает именно такую информацию. "This function" из описания можно убрать, это не несет никакой дополнительной информации.